Can't use Flutter in VS Code - because of git?
In a vs code, terminal, I get this

PS G:\Flutter\MyMapApp>  git --version
git version 2.46.0.windows.1 PS
G:\Flutter\MyMapApp> flutter --version
Error: Unable to find git in your PATH.

What gives? Why is Flutter reliant on git, and why that error when got is obviously installed?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51263438/how-to-solve-unable-to-find-git-in-your-path-on-flutter

Thanks, that worked. Don't know whether to close this, or leave it open for others who might search super user, not s.o, since that question is no longer on-topic for s.o. If you post an answer, I will certainly accept it

Too lazy to touch this topic. Feel free to submit your own
